# How to allow entry in one table if condition is true in other table. - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
products - id, name, brand_id
brands - brand_id, bname
```

If user tries to enter in products say (100, 'xyz', 25); but 25 is not present in brands. then DB engine should not enter above entry in database.

What constraints should i put and where to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It's need foreign key constrain

**PRODUCT**

```
brand_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES brands(brand_id)
```